# differences between xcode interface builder and IOS simulator

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, ios-simulator

I'm new to Xcode and I'm having a problem between interface builder and iphone simulator

As you see below, I set the imageview size for simulator, but some buttons places are changed, button texts disappeared or even buttons disappeared.

http://postimage.org/image/w9ej1c3z1/

I just open a new project and add buttons like the image below, then run the project. Same thing again! I'm doing something wrong?

http://postimage.org/image/6gl55tehd/

xcode version is: 4.5.2

Ios simulator version is 6.0

Comment: Check your autolayout masks in the simulator

Answer (score 1):

Please make validate your design by clicking on "Apply retina 4 form Factor" button at the bottom of view controller upon selection...

if you click on that button, It will change to simulator size and you can check the design

Comment: Sometimes I have the ""Apply Retina 4 form factor" button, sometimes not. How can I get that button to display when it is not dishlaying.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface builder is set for the resolution of an iPhone 5. Your simulator is on the resolution of an iPhone 4S. In the Simulator menu bar select `Device -> Hardware - iPhone 5 (Retina)` and you will see your additional buttons.

Here is a pretty good tutorial which explains how to support both the iPhone 5 and <= iPhone 4S screen resolutions. [Working with iOS 6 Auto Layout Constraints in Interface Builder](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Interface_Builder)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your view is for a 4" screen but you are running in the 3.5" simulator. You will probably just need to play with the autoresize a bit to make it work correctly.